# Calculating the probability of letter assignment

Tags: probability, combinatorics

We have 10 letters written to 10 different friends and the 10 addressed envelops. The letters are put
into the envelops at random, that is, all 10! assignment are equally likely.

(a) What is the probability that the first 5 letters and only those are in the right envelop?

(b) What is the probability that exactly 5 letters are in the right envelop?

For this question you are suppose to use the inclusion exclusion principle. But I'm not sure how you use it.

Comment: (a): (_probability that at least the first 5 letters are in the right envelope_) - (_probability that none of the remaining 5 letters are in their right envelopes_).

Comment: (b): _choose_ which 5 of the 10 letters are in their right envelope: $10\choose 5$ ways to do that. Then apply strategy of (a).